# Group by non existent column or include null values in sql server 2012 clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have this query:

```
    SELECT 1 as Tipo, 'Total Efectivo'
    AS tipo_pago,
    ISNULL(SUM(p.monto), 0) AS Total,
    suc.su_nombre AS Sucursal
    FROM Comprobante c
    RIGHT JOIN Pago p ON c.co_idcomp = p.co_idcomp
    LEFT JOIN PagoCheque pc ON p.id_pago = pc.id_pago
    LEFT JOIN Cheque ch ON pc.id_cheque = ch.id_cheque
    LEFT JOIN PagoBoletaDeposito pbd ON p.id_pago = pbd.id_pago
    LEFT JOIN BoletaDeposito bd ON pbd.id_boleta_deposito = bd.id_boleta_deposito
    LEFT JOIN Movimientos m ON p.mv_id = m.mv_id
    LEFT JOIN Sorteos s ON m.so_id = s.so_id
    LEFT JOIN Clientes cl ON m.cl_id = cl.cl_id
    LEFT JOIN Sucursales suc ON m.su_id = suc.su_id
    WHERE p.esta_eliminado = 0 AND p.tipo_pago = 1 AND m.cl_id = 14 AND m.su_id = 1
    GROUP BY suc.su_nombre
    UNION
    SELECT 2 as Tipo, 'Total Premios'
    AS tipo_pago,
    ISNULL(SUM(p.monto), 0) AS Total,
    suc.su_nombre AS Sucursal
    FROM Comprobante c
    RIGHT JOIN Pago p ON c.co_idcomp = p.co_idcomp
    LEFT JOIN PagoCheque pc ON p.id_pago = pc.id_pago
    LEFT JOIN Cheque ch ON pc.id_cheque = ch.id_cheque
    LEFT JOIN PagoBoletaDeposito pbd ON p.id_pago = pbd.id_pago
    LEFT JOIN BoletaDeposito bd ON pbd.id_boleta_deposito = bd.id_boleta_deposito
    LEFT JOIN Movimientos m ON p.mv_id = m.mv_id
    LEFT JOIN Sorteos s ON m.so_id = s.so_id
    LEFT JOIN Clientes cl ON m.cl_id = cl.cl_id
    LEFT JOIN Sucursales suc ON m.su_id = suc.su_id
    WHERE p.esta_eliminado = 0 AND p.tipo_pago = 2 AND m.cl_id = 14 AND m.su_id = 1
    GROUP BY suc.su_nombre
UNION
SELECT 5 as Tipo, 'Total General' AS tipo_pago,
        ISNULL(SUM(p.monto), 0) AS Total,
        suc.su_nombre AS Sucursal
FROM Comprobante c
RIGHT JOIN Pago p ON c.co_idcomp = p.co_idcomp
LEFT JOIN PagoCheque pc ON p.id_pago = pc.id_pago
LEFT JOIN Cheque ch ON pc.id_cheque = ch.id_cheque
LEFT JOIN PagoBoletaDeposito pbd ON p.id_pago = pbd.id_pago
LEFT JOIN BoletaDeposito bd ON pbd.id_boleta_deposito = bd.id_boleta_deposito
LEFT JOIN Movimientos m ON p.mv_id = m.mv_id
LEFT JOIN Sorteos s ON m.so_id = s.so_id
LEFT JOIN Clientes cl ON m.cl_id = cl.cl_id 
LEFT JOIN Sucursales suc ON m.su_id = suc.su_id
WHERE p.esta_eliminado = 0  AND m.cl_id = 14 AND m.su_id = 1 
GROUP BY suc.su_nombre
```

My problem is that if there is no value on the second union, then the results aren't show but i want to include them even if they are null.
But i cant GROUP BY the column tipo_pago because it gives me an error.

Is there some possibility to include this values?

UPDATE: Watching the answers i need to clarify that i can't make one single query and i need to maintain the UNION and both queries.

UPDATE 2: It's been my fault to give a wrong query, i was missing the important part of the query with out realize. There is a third UNION that makes the SUM of all the tipo_pago

Comment: Why is it union and not union all? There can't be duplicates by definition so this is just extra work for nothing. Also why `c RIGHT JOIN p LEFT JOIN pc` instead of `p LEFT JOIN c LEFT JOIN pc`? Right joins are downright unintuitive and make people think a lot harder when trying to read your query. Finally, referencing `m` in the where clause makes that an inner join, not a left join.

Comment: Why do you have to use the Union if it is functionally unnecessary and inefficient?  My answer should give you a record for both tipo_pago values (1 and 2) even if there is no data for one or the other.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you your final grand total row.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do this as a single query? Something like this should be close.

```
SELECT p.tipo_pago as Tipo
    , case p.tipo_pago when 1 then 'Total Efectivo' else 'Total Premios' end AS tipo_pago
    , ISNULL(SUM(p.monto), 0) AS Total
    , suc.su_nombre AS Sucursal
FROM Comprobante c
RIGHT JOIN Pago p ON c.co_idcomp = p.co_idcomp
LEFT JOIN PagoCheque pc ON p.id_pago = pc.id_pago
LEFT JOIN Cheque ch ON pc.id_cheque = ch.id_cheque
LEFT JOIN PagoBoletaDeposito pbd ON p.id_pago = pbd.id_pago
LEFT JOIN BoletaDeposito bd ON pbd.id_boleta_deposito = bd.id_boleta_deposito
LEFT JOIN Movimientos m ON p.mv_id = m.mv_id
LEFT JOIN Sorteos s ON m.so_id = s.so_id
LEFT JOIN Clientes cl ON m.cl_id = cl.cl_id
LEFT JOIN Sucursales suc ON m.su_id = suc.su_id
WHERE p.esta_eliminado = 0 
    AND p.tipo_pago in (1, 2) 
    AND m.cl_id = 14 
    AND m.su_id = 1
GROUP BY p.tipo_pago
    , suc.su_nombre
ORDER BY p.tipo_pago
```

Comment: because the column tipo_pago is not an existent column

Comment: Huh??? How is it nonexistant. You have it right there in your query. You reference that column in your where clause but then you also have a derived column with the same name.

Comment: You are completely right, my mistake... i will check your query

Answer (score 0):

You can add a values statement in your from clause to ensure that you get both values of tipo_pago.  You can use grouping sets to get your final grand total row.  Like:

```
SELECT isnull(a.pago, 5) as Tipo, 
    case when a.pago=1 then
        'Total Efectivo' 
    when a.pago=2 then
        'Total Premios'
    else
        'Total General'
    end AS tipo_pago,
    ISNULL(SUM(p.monto), 0) AS Total,
    suc.su_nombre AS Sucursal
from (values (1),(2)) a(pago) 
LEFT JOIN Pago p on a.pago = p.tipo_pago
LEFT JOIN Comprobante c ON c.co_idcomp = p.co_idcomp
LEFT JOIN PagoCheque pc ON p.id_pago = pc.id_pago
LEFT JOIN Cheque ch ON pc.id_cheque = ch.id_cheque
LEFT JOIN PagoBoletaDeposito pbd ON p.id_pago = pbd.id_pago
LEFT JOIN BoletaDeposito bd ON pbd.id_boleta_deposito = bd.id_boleta_deposito
LEFT JOIN Movimientos m ON p.mv_id = m.mv_id
LEFT JOIN Sorteos s ON m.so_id = s.so_id
LEFT JOIN Clientes cl ON m.cl_id = cl.cl_id
LEFT JOIN Sucursales suc ON m.su_id = suc.su_id
WHERE p.esta_eliminado = 0 AND m.cl_id = 14 AND m.su_id = 1
group by grouping sets ((a.pago, suc.su_nombre),())
```